# Error in some import statements in my "Simple Spring Hibernate Utility Project"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite (STS) Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE. I have created a "Spring Template Project" as "Simple Spring Hibernate Utility Project". The following import statements in "HibernateConfiguration.java" file could not be resolved:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

What to do for resolving the problem/error?

Comment: have you added the jar files to your classpath?

Comment: @Abu: What jar file should be added?

Comment: @ ripon you only gave the answer !!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in "pom.xml":

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```